# Android Bluetooth Diffeent Behaviour after first run

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have spent the afternoon reading all the post on here to do with bluetooth and android. There have been a few posts related to my long standing problem which is my app runs fine when i first open it and use a bluetooth connection.

However, when i exit the app and re enter it a bit later the bluetooth data stream crashes. No explanation in the log, nothing.

I am closing the bluetooth input and output streams, closing the socket and the disconnection takes place on the other side also.

Why does the app behave differently when re entering it for a second time or more?

I am testing on an Advent Vega tablet,

I am trying `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);` after closing socket, then calling finish. All threads print there very last line of the run method so i know they are dying gracefully.